# SAD Therapy Light Specifications?

Tags: vision

I keep running into alternative theories and facts about what specification of light to use in sun lamps for light therapy treatment.

Many actual afflicted people seem to just swear by just [pumping as much light as humanly possible onto a person's eyes](https://meaningness.com/metablog/sad-light-lumens). I am talking up to thousands of watts, commercial LED flood lights. Other articles seem to place [more importance on the color](https://ask.metafilter.com/47461/Sad-lightboxes-make-me-happy), and sometimes even on the exact frequency graph. And all consumer products seem to be small tablets you place about 6 inches from your face.

What, according to research, is the best setup for treating SAD? Is there an optimal color and intensity or is it just about increasing light available?

Answer (score 0):

All I know is u want a SAD lamp with: at least 10,000lux a reasonable distance away-like 12”,full spectrum, up to 6500K, and a CRI over 95.

Those are all for the best kind of SAD lamp..which is also hard to find ALL those specs in one light..so it’s gonna be spendy to find that.

If u want cheaper u can certainly find 10,000lux at a 4-6” distance away, full spectrum up to 6000K, and a CRI around 90..that would make for a decent SAD lamp, just not the best.

Also, a light that projects downward(like the sun does) is best-but also hard to find along with all those other specs.

I’ve spent hours n hours trying to find the best(but also not so expensive) one, and I’m sick of it. So if anyone has recommendations, please share!